# Does Codepush create the full bundle ( original js files +modified js files ) or only the delta ( modified js files ) in React native?

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

If Codepush really creates the bundle of only modified js files, how exactly in this delta checked?

Answer (score 3):

On client side CodePush always generate full bundle which is sent to the server (when doing CodePush release command).

On server there is a logic to determine if requested CodePush update could be sent partially or client needs full update.

At that moment CodePush support only file-base diffing, so only updated and new files are sent to client devices.

Comment: Thanks for this info.